# Kentico page security and a CSS List Menu webpart

Tags: kentico

This is odd. I have a section that is visible to roles B, P, S, and H.

Here is the section structure.

- Resources

  - Branch Directors

    - Sales Reports
    - Memos
    - Forms
    - Presentations
  - Sales Reports
  - Memos
  - Forms
  - Presentations

The Branch Directors should only be visible to people in role B. What i'm seeing is, if someone from role S is on Forms, they do not see the Branch Directors section. If they go to Memos, it appears.

Memos, Forms, Presentations, and Sales Reports are all different templates, but i've doubled checked the list menu webpart and can't see what i'm missing. Where else should i look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the setting "check security" on the menu web part?

Comment: This was probably it. I'll be the first to call myself an idiot over missing little things!

Answer (score 1):

May be a macro signing issue possibly, try going to System -> Macros -> Signature and resign the macros, sometimes that resolves weird bugs like that.

Also try System -> Clear Cache in case it's a caching issue (cached before you made the change)

Otherwise take a look at the CSS List Menu webpart and see if there are settings differences between the two pages.

Comment: I think @Boris P. had it correct. Just not sure if it was always like this, or someone changed it.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, i copied the list menu from a page that was fine to the memos page, compared settings and both looked the same. Checked in a browser and the new webpart worked, while original didn't.

I've removed the original while i test further.